# How can I add an application groups with C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory, addition, active-directory-group

I want to add a new application group in the active directory with a website. I don't know how I can do that, I copied some code from a website (I don't know anymore the url). I know there are some other similar questions, but I don't understand it...

```
string newGroup = "_app_" + 
string ouPath = "OU=Application Groups,OU=Global,OU=Groups,DC="*domain*";
if (!DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://CN=" + newGroup + "," + ouPath))
{
    try
    {
        // bind to the container, e.g. LDAP://cn=Users,dc=...
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ouPath);

        // create group entry
        DirectoryEntry group = entry.Children.Add("CN=" + newGroup, "group");

        // set properties
        group.Properties["sAmAccountName"].Value = newGroup;
        group.Properties["GroupScope"].Value = "Global";
        group.Properties["GroupCategory"].Value = "Security";
        group.Properties["-Description"].Value = "SelfService" + System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        // save group
        group.CommitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
    }
}
else { Console.WriteLine(ouPath + " already exists"); }
```

Comment: You just need to check if a user is in a certain ad group - that code adds a group to ad... which is fairly obvious from "newgroup" and ".add"

Comment: *new application group in the active directory with a website.* - you mean from a website? Whats the problem? any errors? need more info.. please read [ask].

Comment: I haven't any errors, it just doesn't work